# Find $\frac{\partial }{\partial a_{i,j}} c^{T} (s^{\ast} \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})^{-1} b c^{T} (s \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})^{-1} b $

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to find:

$$ \frac{\partial H }{\partial a_{i,j}} = \frac{\partial }{\partial a_{i,j}} \mathbf{c}^{T} (s^{\ast} \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})^{-1} \mathbf{b} \mathbf{c}^{T} (s \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})^{-1} \mathbf{b}  $$

where $s^{\ast}$ is the complex conjugate of $s$, $s$ being a constant, $\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{A}$ are all real and $\mathbf{c},\mathbf{b}$ do not depend on $\mathbf{A}$.

---

**Attempt at an answer:**

Since $H()$ us a scalar function, we know from the matrix cookbook that:

$$ \frac{\partial H }{\partial a_{i,j}} = \text{tr}\left( \left[ \frac{ \partial H}{\partial \mathbf{A}}  \right]^{H} \frac{ \partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial a_{i,j}}   \right) $$

However, I am not sure how to find $\frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{A}}$. Can I get some help here? I have a heap of computations, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere...

Comment: Let $\def\l{\lambda}\def\n{\nabla}\,\l=c^T(sI-A)^{-1}b,\,$ then you want
$\,\n(\l^*\l) = 2\;{\cal Re}(\l^*\,\n\l),\,$ where $\,\n\l\,$ is known from your [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4464105) question.

Comment: @greg Okay so $ \frac{\partial  }{\partial a_{i,j}} \lambda^{\ast} \lambda = \lambda^{\ast} \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial a_{i,j}} + \frac{\partial \lambda^{\ast}}{\partial a_{i,j}} \lambda = 2 \text{Re} \left\{ \lambda^{\ast} \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial a_{i,j}}   \right\}$. And we know $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial a_{i,j}}$ already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(A)=c^T(sI-A)^{-1}b$. Using $dX^{-1}=-X^{-1}(dX)X^{-1}$, we get
\begin{aligned}
df(A)
&=c^T\left[d(zI-A)^{-1}\right]b\\
&=-c^T(sI-A)^{-1}\left[d(sI-A)\right](sI-A)^{-1}b\\
&=c^T(sI-A)^{-1}(dA)(sI-A)^{-1}b.
\end{aligned}
Since $A$ is real, $\overline{df(A)}=d\overline{f(A)}$. Therefore
\begin{aligned}
dH=d\left(\overline{f(A)}f(A)\right)
&=d\overline{f(A)}f(A)+\overline{f(A)}df(A)\\
&=\overline{df(A)}f(A)+\overline{f(A)}df(A)\\
&=2\operatorname{Re}\left(\overline{f(A)}df(A)\right)\\
&=2\operatorname{Re}\left(c^T(s^\ast I-A)^{-1}b\ c^T(sI-A)^{-1}(dA)(sI-A)^{-1}b\right).\\
\end{aligned}
Let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb C^n$. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial a_{ij}}
&=2\operatorname{Re}\left[
c^T(s^\ast I-A)^{-1}b
\ c^T(sI-A)^{-1}e_i
\ e_j^T(sI-A)^{-1}b\right]\\
&=2\operatorname{Re}\left[e_j^T(sI-A)^{-1}b\ c^T(s^\ast I-A)^{-1}b\ c^T(sI-A)^{-1}e_i\right]\\
&=g_{ij}\\
\end{aligned}
where $g_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry of the matrix
$$
G=2\operatorname{Re}\left[(sI-A)^{-1}b\ c^T(s^\ast I-A)^{-1}b\ c^T(sI-A)^{-1}\right]^{\ T}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for this super complete answer!